# How to install PHP Opcache on MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: php, macos, php-7.1, macos-high-sierra, opcache

I'm using the standard Apache and PHP 7.1 (not Homebrew) that comes with Mac High Sierra. However, it appears that this version doesn't have Opcache enabled even though it should come as standard with PHP 7. It's even listed in `phpinfo()` under "Module Authors", but no section showing it's actually installed. Calling `opcache_get_status` gives a fatal error.

I've installed the extension via Homebrew, and linked the `opcache.so` file. It appears to be working on the CLI but not in Apache. For some reason the CLI and web are using different ini files:

- `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini` for CLI
- `/etc/php.ini` for web

The CLI is parsing the addition files including `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini`, and `php -i` shows Opcache. But `phpinfo()` in the browser does not - no additional ini files are parsed.

I currently have this in `/etc/php.ini`:

```
[opcache]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-opcache/opcache.so"
opcache.enable=1
```

But still nothing. I followed the exact same process for xdebug and it worked fine. What am I missing?

---

I wonder if it would be easier to use the Homebrew version of PHP. But I don't appear to have the required `.so` file. Various tutorials say to put this in Apache's `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

But the `libexec` directory does not exist. There is `lib` but neither this nor any other directory has any `.so` file.

Comment: Can you confirm that you dont have any other PHP versions installed and are running 7.1 from a phpinfo() ?

Comment: Yes that’s right. I was using PHP 5.5 from Homebrew before I upgraded to High Sierra but uninstalled it after upgrading. phpinfo now shows v7.1.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @Ice76 No, I did all that before I asked the question.

Comment: Is "opcache.enable=1" in your /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini ?

Comment: @ASOlivieri No, but PHP (in the browser) isn't using that ini file anyway. But I've just tried adding that - no difference.

Comment: Damn. Configuring ini files is horrible. Sorry. Sanity check: are you restarting Apache after changing ini files with sudo apachectl -k restart ?

Comment: Yes, and that works fine for other modules (I just installed mcrypt same as xdebug above, with no problems).

Comment: This walk-through is saying to unload the provisioned Apache and reload with homebrew. It doesn't say why though. Maybe this is a workaround for a similar issue? https://gist.github.com/DragonBe/0faebe58deced34744953e3bf6afbec7

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For me it worked by these steps:

1. Search `extension_dir` in "phpinfo()" page, I got a path 
   `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`
2. By execute `ls -lh /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`, I found "opcache.so" , I guess it's installed when upgraded to "High Sierra"
3. Create "/etc/php.ini" (by copy "/etc/php.ini.default"), and modify:

> ```
> [opcache]
> zend_extension = opcache.so
> opcache.enable = 1
> ```

4. Restart apache, module "opcache" is enabled

---

**EDIT / CONCLUSION**

Since "opcache extension" is installed on Mac OS High Sierra by default, the solution of enabling opcahe on Mac OS High Sierra is:

- Create "/etc/php.ini" if you don't have one, by simply copy the default configuration: `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`
- Add `zend_extension = opcache.so` to `/etc/php.ini` and set "opcache" enable:

php.ini opcache section looks like:

```
[opcache]
zend_extension = opcache.so
opcache.enable = 1
```

Comment: Why is `zend_extension = opcache.so` needed?

Comment: @YesBarry, See [opcache installation](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php), _OPcache can only be compiled as a shared extension. Once compiled, you can use the zend_extension configuration directive to load the OPcache extension into PHP. This can be done with zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so_

Answer (score 2):

## PHP Opcache Error on MacOS

This happened to me, so i hope it helps others.

When running php cli commands, warnings about opcache loading were displayed:

```
$ php -v
Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so' (no such file)
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2023 16:25:32) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

### Version Info:

- MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 (but i'm pretty sure this stands for any MacOS version).
- Homebrew 4.0.11

### Background

I had installed php 5.6 for a legacy project.  I then switched to php 8.2.  I had installed 5.6 with a download from php.net.  I installed php 8.2 using `brew`. *(Spoiler alert, the 5.6 install seems to have left behind an extra ini file).*

## Locate opcache.so/php.ini

1. Find your php.ini by looking at [`phpinfo()`](https://php.net/phpinfo).
2. Find all versions of opcache. I used [`locate`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383610/when-should-we-enable-the-locate-command-on-a-mac) which may or may not be enabled on your mac.  Another option would be to use `find / -name opcache.so` but that could take a while and would need to be run via `sudo` maybe.

#### phpinfo() output

My `phpinfo()` showed an additional ini file parsed:

[image]

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so
```

*More on this below, for now, let's find out what opcache.so exist...*.

#### `locate opcache.so`

Here are all the opcache.so that were found on my system:

```
$ locate opcache.so
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.4/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so
/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40_6/lib/php/20131226/opcache.so
/usr/local/php5-7.3.8-20190811-205217/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/opcache.so
```

There are three.  The 8.2 opcache.so (the one i want to use with php 8.2), the 5.6 opcache.so (a second one included by `brew`, since i also installed 5.6 using brew), and then the php.net installed 5.7 opcache.so.

> Now that we know (a) why php can't find it (errant ini file content) and (b) the path to the ini file we do want to use), we simply update the ini file to point to the right opcache.so file.

### Shutup jj, fix the issue

The extra ini file was pointing to the wrong opcache.so file.

*Edit the opcache ini file and fix php opcache:*

```
[opcache]
;zend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.4/lib/php/20220829/opcache.so
```

*(The semi-colon is a comment; i left the old line there for future reference).*

Result:

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2023 16:25:32) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

*(The error is no longer evident now that the extra parsed ini file points to the correct opcache.so file.)*

Comment: Thank you very much! Only your answer helped me!